# Tkinter import problem

Tags: python, tkinter, tkmessagebox

I suspect I've got something very simple wrong here but I can't spot what. The following code:

```
import Tkinter as Tk
Tk.tkMessageBox.showerror(message='some error')
```

gives:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'tkMessageBox'
```

Widgets (e.g. Button, Entry) work ok. Interactively I get the same result, and also:

```
>>> import Tkinter as Tk
>>> print Tkinter
<module 'Tkinter' from 'C:\Python26\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.pyc'>
```

and tkMessageBox.py *is* in C:\Python26\Lib\lib-tk. Although why is the capitalization of Lib/lib different?!

This is with Python 2.6 on windows, and running Tkinter._test() reports version 8.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you meant this:

```
import tkMessageBox
tkMessageBox.showerror(message='some error')
```

Comment: So I did, thanks! But why, isn't tkMessageBox a submodule of the package Tkinter?

Comment: @lost: I'm not sure, but I think the `Tkinter` module is just a pure port of Tcl/Tk API into Python with no new stuff, while `tkMessageBox` is a script built ontop of that API. Open up `tkMessageBox.py` and you'll see :)